# MsSql Scheduled Event to firing

Tags: mysql

I have registered an event scheduler to run on every week monday, And done all the steps asked to follow from googling. . I have backdated the server date to monday date.But still the event is not getting fired.

Step 1 Set even scheduler on:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

step 2 Create event:

```
CREATE EVENT ScheduledFaMeetingTableUpdate
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
  STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY + INTERVAL 10 HOUR
    DO 
    Call FAMeetingWeekUpdate_sp();

SELECT @@global.event_scheduler; 
Result : ON

Show Events;
Result :
'bitnami_redmine', 'ScheduledFaMeetingTableUpdate', 'root@localhost', 'SYSTEM', 'RECURRING', NULL, '1', 'WEEK', '2017-08-14 10:00:00', NULL, 'ENABLED', '0', 'utf8', 'utf8_general_ci', 'utf8_general_ci'


SHOW PROCESSLIST;
Result :
'1', 'event_scheduler', 'localhost', NULL, 'Daemon', '-65135', 'Waiting for next activation', NULL
```

Comment: MySQL or MsSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified, that the event should be executed again and again.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html):

> Normally, once an event has expired, it is immediately dropped. You can override this behavior by specifying ON COMPLETION PRESERVE. Using ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE merely makes the default nonpersistent behavior explicit.

Your create event statement should look like this:

```
CREATE EVENT ScheduledFaMeetingTableUpdate
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY + INTERVAL 10 HOUR
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
    Call FAMeetingWeekUpdate_sp();
```